# Why are images loading slowly on my website?

Tags: image-upload, media-images

Our company is engaged in the production of mobile loading ramps, our website is https://ausbaurampa.de we have encountered a problem with slow loading of photos on the site. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using GTMETRIX.COM to analyze

https://ausbaurampa.de/catalog/verladerampen/

And look in detail at STRUCTURE results,
#1 suggests Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN)
#9 suggests Efficiently Encode Images (minify for size reduction)
#11 suggests Serve images in next-gen formats
Image formats like WebP and AVIF for ~ 50 reduction in size
rather than jpg and png.

View profile for contact info.